# C# Github API Unable to create issue

Tags: c#, post, github

Im unable to create an issue on github even though its supposed to work. I do manage to get something back out of it for some reason.

What i am trying to do is uploading a string in json format that has the same feature as POST. Apparently that is not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateGithubIssue("Test Issue - C#", "This is just a test to check if i can manage to create an issue from C#.");
        }
        static string username = "someUser";
        static string password = "somePassword";

        static string repoIssueLink = "http://api.github.com/repos/someUser/someRepo/issues";

        public static void CreateGithubIssue(string Title, string Description)
        {

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

            string jsonPost = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Issue(Title, Description), Formatting.Indented);

            string response = webClient.UploadString(repoIssueLink, jsonPost);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonPost);

        }
    }

    public class Issue
    {
        public string title;
        public string body;
        public List<string> assignees;
        public int milestone;
        public List<string> labels;

        public Issue(string title = "Default Title", string body = "Default Body", List<string> assignees = null, int milestone = 0, List<string> labels = null)
        {
            if (assignees == null) assignees = new List<string>();
            if (labels == null) labels = new List<string>();

            this.title = title;
            this.body = body;
            this.assignees = assignees;
            this.milestone = milestone;
            this.labels = labels;
        }
    }
}
```

The Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: You're serializing it twice

Comment: oh, whoops. I forgot to change that.

Comment: What's the output look like?

Comment: A Json Output, just what you see when you look in the browser. A long long list of items.

Comment: https://imgur.com/h516gj5

Comment: Have you tried using the https url for the api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161770/discussion-between-thaun-and-1-618).

Comment: It looks like it worked perfectly. That output in your screenshot matches what is in your issuelist: https://github.com/MoonEdge/Moonlit-Issues/issues/1

Comment: No, that was created manually.

Comment: Trying to create less commenting here using the chat place, but @1.618 , yes i have tried, and it gave me an 404 exception, file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after asking some other people, i managed to find the answer.
I changed the link to HTTPS and used this code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);

string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Issue(Title, Description), Formatting.Indented);

string response = webClient.UploadString(repoIssueLink, jsonOutput);
Console.WriteLine(response);
Console.WriteLine(jsonOutput);
```